# Are some moderators helping too much?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation, vote-to-close, etiquette

I clicked on the [review link](https://pets.stackexchange.com/review) and noticed one person, who is a moderator, has the the most recent review history on all 6 review tasks.

I wonder, if one person (particularly a moderator) can adversely impact the site by trying to help too much.  As I am that person, I wonder if I should review less, or pass on the moderator hat, or otherwise modify my habits?

Thoughts and constructive criticism encouraged, in response.

Comment: There's no single answer to that, but I generally let the community take first pass at it.

Comment: I generally consider it this way: do we have an active enough community that they can take on those cleanup tasks? If so, then I tend to leave the review queues alone unless they get randomly really large for some reason. If not, then I figure I am still a part of the community, and thus can help out with those tasks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see no problem with moderators being active in the "suggested edits",  "first posts", and "late answers" queues, as nothing there is subject to a vote.  (Yes, technically you can unilaterally approve an edit that would otherwise require two people, but that's no big deal.)  On sites where I moderate I tend to be less active in the "close", "reopen", and "low quality" queues because my actions are binding.  But if stuff is piling up or there doesn't seem to be much activity, I see no problem with mods going there too.  You can skip anything that's not crystal clear.

Another tool you can use for the close queue is filtering.  I sometimes restrict my close-vote reviews to duplicates because (a) they're more straightforward and (b) finding them helps all involved (it gets the OP an answer).

Comment: I like all of your thoughts there. One of my concerns is lack of community participation, if most of the mundane tasks are regularly done by a few high rep and/or diamond members is that discouraging the new members from taking on those tasks?

Comment: @JamesJenkins yes, that's a concern -- and, as you said, it's not just mods but "the few regulars", whoever they are.  Sometimes a reminder that reviewers are wanted is enough; let's see if your post changes anything.